# Read partially encoded file (each line encoded separately)

Tags: python, character-encoding

Given the following file:

```
b'Clay Regazzoni' 
b"Gianclaudio Giuseppe Regazzoni, dit Clay Regazzoni, n\xe9 le \xe0"

b'Lucie de Syracuse' 
b'Lucie de Syracuse ou sainte Lucie, vierge et martyre dont le nom est illustr\xe9'
```

How can I extract and decode each line separately?
Each line was separately encoded using `utf-8`, but the file was stored using the default encoding.

My attempt was

```
open('path','r').readlines()[1].decode('latin1')
```

which fails (`str has no decode attribiute`), as

```
secondline = 'b"Gianclaudio Giuseppe Regazzoni, dit Clay Regazzoni, n\xe9 le \xe0"'
and not 
secondline = b"Gianclaudio Giuseppe Regazzoni, dit Clay Regazzoni, n\xe9 le \xe0"
```

The desired output is

```
>>>open('path','r').readlines()[1].decode('latin1')
Gianclaudio Giuseppe Regazzoni, dit Clay Regazzoni, né le à
```

Comment: Your problem description does not make sense.  This is not UTF-8 and it is unclear what (you think) the "default encoding" is. It looks like maybe the encoding is actually Latin-1 but the information is exposed in a rather non-standard way. Can you instead show a hex dump of a couple of lines around one of the promlem spots? If the file genuinely contains a mixture of different encodings, can you establish a list of encoding candidates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply [`ast` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) as follows:

```
import ast
with open('x.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line[0:2] == 'b"' or line[0:2] == "b'":
            print(ast.literal_eval(line).decode('latin1'))
        else:
            print(line)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> Clay Regazzoni
> Gianclaudio Giuseppe Regazzoni, dit Clay Regazzoni, né le à
>
>
> Lucie de Syracuse
> Lucie de Syracuse ou sainte Lucie, vierge et martyre dont le nom est illustré
> ```